# How to get the value of the objective function from glmnet in R?

Tags: r, glmnet

I can obtain a lasso or ridge regression fit with

```
cvfit <- cv.glmnet(X, y)
```

I know how to get the best value of lambda out

```
lambda.min <- cvfit$lambda.min
```

and how to get the best mean squared error out

```
mse <- cvfit$cvm[cvfit$lambda == lambda.min]
```

How can I get the value of the objective function?

Comment: MSE = objective function for linear regression.

Comment: Yes, for ordinary linear regression, but not for lasso or ridge regression. In lasso for example the objective function is MSE+lambda*|A| where A are the coefficients.

Comment: @rhombidodecahedron You are correct about the objective function. The lasso indeed minimises the objective function "residual sum of squares + lambda * | coefficients |".

Comment: `cvfit$lambda[cvfit$lambda == cvfit$lambda.min]` is just `cvfit$lambda.min` by the way :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if `glmnet` gives access to the value of the objective function, but it is easy to calculate ourselves. Here is a little example for LASSO.

```
library(glmnet)

x <- as.matrix(mtcars[c("hp", "cyl", "wt", "gear")])
y <- mtcars$mpg

cvfit = cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha = 1)  # alpha = 1 for LASSO
```

We can use `coef` to get the model's coefficients, and then calculate the objective function value from its definition.

```
coefs <- coef(cvfit, s = "lambda.min")
objective <- sum((y - coefs[1] - (x %*% coefs[-1]))^2) + 
             cvfit$lambda.min * sum(abs(coefs[-1]))
objective
```

Ridge regression is similar: use `alpha = 0` instead and replace `sum(abs(coefs[-1]))` with `sum(coefs[-1]^2)`.

Comment: Thanks, looks good. I'm wondering: I think glmnet standardizes all variables during the regression. Is it important to standardize them again when calculating the objective function?